# How can I constrain the a flexbox to the width of its first child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple layout with two rows. The top row should determine the width (based on its content, not a css value), and the two elements in the bottom row should expand to match that width:

```
---------------------------------
| row one is exactly this wide  |
---------------------------------
| [...thing1...] [...thing2...] |
---------------------------------
```

```
<div.parent style='display: flex; flex-direction: column'>
  <div.row1>row 1 is exactly this wide</div>
  <div.row2 style='flex: 1; display: flex'>
    <span style='flex: 1'>thing1</span>
    <span style='flex: 1'>thing2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `thing1` and `thing2` expand up to their grandparent's width, not `row1`'s:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| row one is exactly this wide                                       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| [..........thing1.............] [............thing2..............] |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I constrain the `parent` div's width to be that of `row1`? Or, how do I achieve a layout like this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that row 1 width must be preserved under all circumstances. The problem with this is that if thing1 or thing2 text gets too large it causes the parent div to increase in size. This can be solved by setting the things div to max-width: min-content and min-width: 50% so both divs occupy the same width but then we set word-break: break-all; so that any block of text will break. See example below

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: max-content;
}

.things {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.things > div {
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: min-content;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div style="header">row 1 is exactly this wide</div>
  <div class='things'>
    <div>thing1IsAVeryLongStringSoItWillCauseTheParentDivToWidenUp</div>
    <div>thing2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise that was easy enough, set both `.parent.width` and `.row1.width` equal to `max-content` and leave the rest as-is.

This way `.parent` is not allowed to exceed its content, which in turn is restricted by the width of `.row1`:

```css
body * { outline: 1px dashed } /* for demo */
```

```html
<div style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: max-content'>
  <div style="width: max-content">row 1 is exactly this wide</div>
  <div style='flex: 1; display: flex'>
    <span style='flex: 1'>thing1</span>
    <span style='flex: 1'>thing2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No padding or additional styling, just a basic idea using JS.

```js
const papa = document.getElementById('papa');
const row1 = document.getElementById('row-1');

const maxWidth = row1.offsetWidth;
papa.style.maxWidth = `${maxWidth + 1}px`;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#papa {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #423232;
}

#row-1 {
  align-self: flex-start; /* Prevent from stretching */
}

#content-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="papa">
  <div id="row-1">Shorter content here. Lorem ipsum epsem</div>
  <div id="content-grid">
    <span class="baby">Some Long content that should split based on row 1.</span>
    <span class="baby">Some Long content that should split based on row 1.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new parent `div` and set it as `display:inline-block`

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div>row 1 is exactly this wide</div>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="flex: 1">thing1</div>
      <div style="flex: 1">thing2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work for me -- `thing1` and `thing2` still extend beyond `row1`.